# How to add a custom attribute to Auth::user() when one logs in

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So, first I hope my title is not misleading. Please let me know if my title fits the question.

QUESTION.
I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I'm trying to find a way to add an attribute "role" to Auth::user() so that I can access it like

```
Auth::user()->role.
```

Role is not a field in the user table used for authentication but it's a value I calculate to get. The reason I ask is I don't want to calculate role every single time I need the value, instead I want to set it when authentication succeeds then reuse it.

Any idea how I can do this?

Or is there any way I can persist a value through out the time a user is logged in so that I can calculate it once and reuse it?

Comment: Auth::user() is recreated on every request or reload , so I suggest you store your calculated role in a session , then create a middle ware which checks if the roles exists then attach the role to the Auth::user() object in that middleware ... Hope it helps

Comment: Okay so I've just read the documentation on middleware and this looks like what I'm looking for. But could tell me how to attach an extra attribute to Auth::user() or could you  point me in the right direction. Is it something like  "$request->user()->role = 23"?

Answer (score 4):

The best way you can achieve this is in your User.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token','is_admin',
        ];

        protected function getRole(){


          if(\Session::has("role")){
            return Session::get("role");
        }else{
           //calculate and save role in session
        }

    }//end get Role

}//end class
```

so you will check it like this

```
Auth::user()->getRole();
```

Make sure you save the role in session after login , the getRole will get it and attach to the user() object , This doesnt need middleware too 
Hope it helps

Comment: This will flush out the session variable when the user logs out, yes?

Comment: Never mind. Figured that last part out. Let me try your solution.

Comment: This returns "call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRole()" ideas?

Comment: Thats strange.. it should work because i have a similar function but mine is isAdmin() and it works well

Comment: @VincentHokie ,no during logout you must flush out the session yourself

Comment: For me User::getRole() works perfectly. Thanks for this though!

Comment: After using the User model in the controller of course

Answer (score 0):

Just add the method of the keyword you want to use at the bottom of the model and use `belongsTo()` to link it up to a corresponding model. Then we just do `Auth::user()->role()` to use it. This is assuming you have a model called Role with a table and roles defined. (laravel 5.2+)

```
public function role() { 
    return $this->belongsTo( Role::class ); 
}
```

The entire model is here:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guarded = ['id', 'remember_token'];

    protected $hidden = [ 'password', 'remember_token' ];

    public static $rules = array(
        'email'  => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'first_name' => 'required|min:2',
        'last_name'  => 'required|min:2'
    );

    public static $rules_password = array(
         'password'  => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
    );

    public function role() { 
        return $this->belongsTo( Role::class ); 
    }

}
```